# Одна кнопка не работает на айфон 6 и ниже

Tags: html, css, iphone

Скрипт не работает на айфон 6 и ниже. На тех, что выше - всё идеально

```
let payBtn = document.getElementById("pay");
    payBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let data = {
        "_csrf-frontend": csrfInput.value,
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        orderID: window.createdOrderID,
      };
      $.ajax({
        url: "/redirect-to-pay",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          if (result.hasOwnProperty("errors")) {
            //показать Alert
          } else {
            document.location.assign(result["link"]);
          }
        },
      });
    });
```

Comment: А где ошибка? Где stacktrace?

Comment: В том то и дело, что ошибок никаких нету, просто не работает и всё

Comment: Вам необходимо привести минимальный воспроизводимый пример.